# How to prevent moving of a window without titlebar but with WS_SYSMENU style?

Tags: winapi

I want to prevent moving of a window which I created before using `CreateWindowEx`.

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, "Title", WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

The most common solution suggested for this is changing the windows style to have no titlebar i.e.

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME));
```

While this solves the problem for drag- & drop at the titlebar, the window is still movable from the control menu (if the window is active press ALT, LEFT, DOWN and select "Move"). I tried using `EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(hWnd, FALSE), SC_MOVE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);` because this is how the disabling for the Close entry works (using `SC_CLOSE` instead of `SC_MOVE`), but it did not disable the Move option.

[image: The control menu where Move shall be disabled]

Is there any way using win32 api to disable only the "Move" option from the context menu without removing the `WS_SYSMENU` style completly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue to disabling the `SC_MOVE` item is in the description of the [`GetSystemMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647985(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

> The system automatically grays items on the standard window menu, depending on the situation. The application can perform its own checking or graying by responding to the WM_INITMENU message that is sent before any menu is displayed.

So even though you're disabling the menu item initially, the system is re-enabling it when the menu is displayed. To fix it, you need to handle `WM_INITMENU` or `WM_INITMENUPOPUP` yourself and override the system's behaviour. For example,
in your window procedure:

```
        case WM_INITMENUPOPUP:
            if (wParam == reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(GetSystemMenu(hWnd, FALSE)))
            {
                // override handling of the system menu
                EnableMenuItem(reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(wParam), SC_MOVE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
                return 0;
            }
            // if WM_INITMENUPOPUP isn't for the system menu, fall through to
            // default processing
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```